# Plotting multiple columns of dataframes in bokeh

Tags: python, pandas, flask, bokeh

I have built a simple flask application. The front end (view) offers two checkboxes A and B that are dataframe columns.

When I select either of the columns, the column values are plotted.

Here is the code.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, request
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file,save
import webbrowser
from threading import Timer
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('sop1.html')

@app.route('/FlaskTutorial',  methods=['POST'])
def user_rec():
    dates = pd.date_range('20130101', periods=100)

    df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 2), index=dates, 
     columns=list('AB'))


    result = request.form 
    signal = request.form.getlist('check')
    print(signal)

    df=pd.DataFrame(df1[signal])

    path=os.getcwd()


    plot=figure(title="Time series data for "+str(df.columns[0])+" 
pair",width=1000,height=600,x_axis_type='datetime',tools='hover')   
    plot.line( source=df,x='index',y=str(df.columns[0]), line_color="blue",legend="spot rate")
output_file(str(path)+'/templates/myplot11.html')
save([plot])

return render_template('myplot11.html', result=result)

def open_browser():
      webbrowser.open_new('http://127.0.0.1:3190/') 

if __name__ == '__main__':

    Timer(1, open_browser).start();
    app.run(port=3190,debug=True)
```

What I want is, both the columns to be plotted (either horizontally or vertically) when I select both the columns.

Here is sop1.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


   <body>


      <form method="post" action="/FlaskTutorial">


      <div class="custom1"> 

        <p>Dataframe columns</p> 

        <input type = "checkbox" name = "check" value = "A"> A <br> </br>
        <input type = "checkbox" name = "check" value = "B"> B<br> </br>



       </div>


     <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="ok"/>    


      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Please suggest the way forward.
My bokeh version is 1.0.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By fluke, I found the solution.

```
result = request.form 
signal = request.form.getlist('check')

dd=[]
for i in range(len(signal)):
    print(i)
    dd.append(bokeh_plot(df1,i))
save([dd[0],dd[1]])
```

And here is the bokeh_plot function

```
def bokeh_plot(df,i):
    path=os.getcwd()
    plot=figure(title="Time series data for "+str(df.columns[i])+" pair",width=1000,height=600,x_axis_type='datetime',tools='hover')   
    plot.line( source=df,x='index',y=str(df.columns[i]), line_color="blue",legend="spot rate")
    output_file(str(path)+'/templates/myplot11.html')
    #save([plot])
    return plot
```